# Edit links in novice users' questions into embedded images?

Tags: discussion, edits, privileges, hyperlinks, images

Users with too low rep cannot embed images in their questions. Those users typically provide a link to the image, and it seems to be common practice for higher rep users to edit the question to embed the image. That way the question is more easily read.

I've done this myself some times. Of course, I do a general check that the linked image is meaningful and that the question is good enough, or at least salvageable. But I'm not sure exactly **what I should check or beware of**. Of course, if the link is blatantly wrong (spam etc) I'll notice. But I'd like to have **specific guidelines** as to what should I be alert to, if there's an **official policy** for that. A related question is why exactly are novice users not allowed to embed the figures themselves.

So, my questions are (**TL;DR**):

- What's the rationale for not allowing novice users to embed images in their questions? What undesired outcomes does that restriction try to prevent, exactly?
- What should I take into account when deciding whether an external link in a novice user's question deserves to be transformed into an embedded image?

Comment: I'm pretty sure spam is a main worry.

Comment: @Daedalus: NSFW also has its place.

Comment: There is a tendency to post a screenshot when a programmer runs into a problem.  Not helpful, Google doesn't index image content.

Comment: And not forgetting just how annoying it is to copy/paste/fix code that someone's screenshotted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What's the rationale for not allowing novice users to embed figures in
>   their questions? What undesired outcomes does that restriction try to
>   prevent, exactly?

I feel this is just a precautions or say user validation before SO allow user to upload image to their question. Otherwise anonymous internet users can take advantage for this, and Reviewer task become more tedious for First Posts Review Queue, and Late Answer Review Queue.

And the main worry is prevent spam through on the SO.

Once user has some upvote on their question or say gain some reputation, then we can say user is somehow trusted or till now user understand some rules and policies how SO works, otherwise SO may be full with spam images.

> What should I take into account when deciding whether an external link
>   in a novice user's question deserves to be transformed into an
>   embedded figure?

Before adding external image link to user's question:-

- Image should be related to question
- should be clear and image content easily visible
- should not be blur
- should add some value to user's question.
- Should not only contains code, user have to add code in text only.

Edit

As suggested by @samgak in comment:- After removing external link and adding image in user's question, don't forget to remove any text which mentioned that "***Sorry, due to low reputation not able to upload images***" or any this kind of text.

Comment: For a good part of the audience, NSFW is probably more troublesome.

Comment: To prevent bad, Good always have to wait?

Comment: The world is imperfect, and SE is no exception. Thus neophyte posters most of the time won't be able to embed an image in their first post, yes. (Unless they have enough rep from association-bonus / suggested edits.)

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName Thanks for the answer. You rise good points. I was hoping there were some kind of "official rules", though

Comment: One thing I would add: after you embed the image, remove any "sorry I don't have enough rep to embed images" text from the question. Perhaps this is stating the obvious, but lots of people don't do it when making these edits.

Comment: @Luis Mendo:- Thanks, I also searched for some official documentation regarding this, but not able to.

Comment: The image should not be a copy of plain text input/output. When I see that, I add the comment "Please insert the text as plain text" and leave the image where it is – not embedded.

Answer (score 12):

I'd say the main types of images you should avoid embedding is:

- Offensive content - an image containing text not appropriate for a question (e.g. offensive language) or one that's NSFW (not safe for work - pornographic, violent, disturbing, etc.).
- Spam - it should look at least vaguely related to the question.
- An image providing clearly and unarguably not useful or redundant information (but relevant to the question) (tread on the side of assuming it's useful if there's any doubt)

While many other types of images are undesirable:

- Code
- Text input/output
- Unclear images
- Images that need a good cropping
- Gigantic images that, when scaled, you can't see what's going on
- Simply way too many images that makes the question too long

In most of these cases, embedding the image does actually improve the question, albeit still some distance away from the ideal question state, so embedding it seems like a good edit.

In these cases you should also comment, pointing out the issue with the image and ask the asker to fix it, but that should go without saying.

---

For gigantic images, I sometimes find it useful to embed it with a link to itself (so clicking the image takes you to the full-size version), so:

```
[![](URL)](same URL again)
```

or

```
[![][1]][1]    # change '1' as appropriate
```

---

For large or many images, it might be useful to [resize the image yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post).

---

> What's the rationale for not allowing novice users to embed figures in their questions? What undesired outcomes does that restriction try to prevent, exactly?

As mentioned in the other answer, any random person on the internet can, without much effort, post something on Stack Overflow. You don't want to make that worse by allowing possibly unpleasant images.

Getting a few upvotes is not as trivial.