# Is SO reputation really needed? Explain why

Tags: discussion, reputation, asking-questions

I ask this because I am new to SO, and while I tried to post a question about Android Studio development with some pictures, it tells me to have at least 10 reputations to upload pictures and use links instead if I don't have enough. Then when I try to upload more than 1 link, it told me I need to have 10 reputation also.

So this sort of prevent me from asking my question with the full details of my problems. Explanation about the necessity of reputation is greatly appreciated.

**PS** If someone tells me to just earn 10+ reputations, it's not easy for me because apparently most of my question have answers already, and the unanswered ones aren't good enough to give me any reputation.

Comment: This is exactly the reson for the rep. limits. To prevent users posting pictures instead of code!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297645

Comment: FWIW, earning reputation is not limited to asking questions. Answering and editing is generally more productive in this regard.

Comment: @AlonEitan,that is a valid point.But to me at least, sometimes some questions are not understandable enough without images

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Unfortunately I am not knowledgeable enough to answer other people's questions

Comment: [Try good, high-quality and substantive edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two reasons why we have reputation-based privileges.

---

The first is the minimization and prevention of spam. Spam doesn't last very long here. Part of this is due to the community's effort, but part of it is the [limitations placed on new users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user).

Spammers would be the first to load up posts with links and images. We don't need that.

The spread of spam is minimized with the limitations on new user comments. In a similar fashion, it takes 100 rep to be able to edit Community Wiki posts.

Edits (to other people's posts) are also kept in check by needing review if the user has less than 2,000 reputation. But getting approval through review gives you 2 rep per edit, so there is a trade off.

---

The other reason we have rep based privileges is the fact that new users don't know how anything works. That's why they do annoying things like post pictures of code and fail to articulate their problems.

Don't ever post pictures of text.

This is merely a fact of life, but it just makes everything run more smoothly if privileges are introduced incrementally. It gives you time to learn how things work, and putting in the time shows dedication.

---

### In other words, reputation is a measure of trust.

That being said, you can actually earn more than enough reputation to post as many images and URLs **without any programming abilities**.

The SE network has 158 sites covering a wide variety of topics. Even [Wood Working](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/). Just earn 200 reputation points by answering questions with your awesome woodworking skills (or something) and you will automatically receive 100 reputation points on Stack Overflow (and every other SE site).

For more information about reputation, see the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).